# How to multiply variable matrix by coefficient matrix in Python, using Gurobi

Tags: python, matrix, multidimensional-array, linear-programming, gurobi

I want to multiply both matrix's below and set as objective for my model:

```
m = gp.Model("matrix")
x = m.addMVar((9, 9), vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="x")
c = np.random.rand(9,9)

m.setObjective(x @ c, GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Here's what am trying to achieve

[image]

This gives me following error:

> Error code -1: Variable is not a 1D MVar object

How can i solve that? I suppose Gurobi doesn't accept 2D Mvar object multiplication

Comment: Are you sure you want to set the expression `x @ matriz_de_coeficients` as objective instead of a constraint? Even if Gurobi would accept it, it doesn't make sense to set the resulting matrix as objective since the evaluated objective always has to return a scalar.

Comment: Now that you mention it, yeah, it's kinda weird. I'm not so sure, but a updated my question. Would you mind take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, note that the product of two matrices is again a matrix and the evaluated objective needs to be a scalar, so this is probably not what you want to do. According to your picture, your objective is a simple linear expression, not a matrix product. Hence, it's much easier to use Gurobi's algebraic modelling interface, i.e. `Var`s instead of `MVars`:

```py
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB, quicksum as qsum
import numpy as np

M, N = 9, 9
m = gp.Model("matrix")
x = m.addVars(M, N, vtype="B", name="x")
c = np.random.rand(M, N)

m.setObjective(qsum(c[i,j]*x[i,j] for i in range(M) for j in range(N)), GRB.MINIMIZE)
```

Comment: It solved the problem. Thank you so much. I need to add the constraints now, the sum of each line must be == 1 and the sum of each column <= 1. Have any tips for doing this? Thank sou again

Comment: You can do something like this ```for i in range(M):
 m.addConstr(qsum(c[i,j]*x[i,j] for j in range(N)) == 1)```